# Google places Autocomplete not working Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

I'm having trouble using the Google Places Autocomplete. I'm following this [tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-google-places-autocomplete-api-example/), I don't get any errors, but the textview isn't giving me predictions when I type a place from my country.

This is my code which is exactly the same from the tutorial

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "Google Places Autocomplete";
    private static final String PLACES_API_BASE = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place";
    private static final String TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE = "/autocomplete";
    private static final String OUT_JSON = "/json";

    private static final String API_KEY = "my api key here";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);

        autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public static ArrayList autocomplete(String input) {
        ArrayList resultList = null;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        StringBuilder jsonResults = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
            sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
            sb.append("&components=country:ph");
            sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));

            URL url = new URL(sb.toString());
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());

            // Load the results into a StringBuilder
            int read;
            char[] buff = new char[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(buff)) != -1) {
                jsonResults.append(buff, 0, read);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error processing Places API URL", e);
            return resultList;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error connecting to Places API", e);
            return resultList;
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }

        try {
            // Create a JSON object hierarchy from the results
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonResults.toString());
            JSONArray predsJsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("predictions");

            // Extract the Place descriptions from the results
            resultList = new ArrayList(predsJsonArray.length());
            for (int i = 0; i < predsJsonArray.length(); i++) {
                System.out.println(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
                System.out.println("============================================================");
                resultList.add(predsJsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("description"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Cannot process JSON results", e);
        }

        return resultList;
    }

    class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {
        private ArrayList resultList;

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int index) {
            return resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

dependecies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            /*
             Retrieve the place ID of the selected item from the Adapter.
             The adapter stores each Place suggestion in a AutocompletePrediction from which we
             read the place ID and title.
              */
            final AutocompletePrediction item = mAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = item.getPlaceId();
            final CharSequence primaryText = item.getDescription();

            Log.i(TAG, "Autocomplete item selected: " + primaryText);

            /*
             Issue a request to the Places Geo Data API to retrieve a Place object with additional
             details about the place.
              */
            mAutocompleteView.setText("");
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            {
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Clicked: " + primaryText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.i(TAG, "Called getPlaceById to get Place details for " + placeId);
        }
    };




private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                // Request did not complete successfully
                Log.e(TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " + places.getStatus().toString());
                places.release();
                return;
            }
            // Get the Place object from the buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            Spanned s;
            // Format details of the place for display and show it in a TextView.
            s=formatPlaceDetails(getResources(),
                    place.getName(),place.getId(), place.getAddress(),
                    place.getPhoneNumber(),place.getWebsiteUri());
            MY_ADDRESS=place.getName().toString();
            getLatlong(place.getId());

            final CharSequence thirdPartyAttribution = places.getAttributions();
            if (thirdPartyAttribution == null) {
               // mPlaceDetailsAttribution.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
               // mPlaceDetailsAttribution.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               // mPlaceDetailsAttribution.setText(Html.fromHtml(thirdPartyAttribution.toString()));
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Place details received: " + place.getName());
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
            places.release();
        }
    };




    private static Spanned formatPlaceDetails(Resources res, CharSequence name, String id,CharSequence address, CharSequence phoneNumber, Uri websiteUri) {
        Log.e(TAG, res.getString(R.string.place_details, name, id, address, phoneNumber, websiteUri));
        return Html.fromHtml(res.getString(R.string.place_details, name, id, address, phoneNumber,websiteUri));
    }
```

**Use this Adapter**

```
/**
 * Created by Alan on 06-11-2015.
 */
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.common.data.DataBufferUtils;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.style.CharacterStyle;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Adapter that handles Autocomplete requests from the Places Geo Data API.
 * {@link AutocompletePrediction} results from the API are frozen and stored directly in this
 * adapter. (See {@link AutocompletePrediction#freeze()}.)
 * <p>
 * Note that this adapter requires a valid {@link com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient}.
 * The API client must be maintained in the encapsulating Activity, including all lifecycle and
 * connection states. The API client must be connected with the {@link Places#GEO_DATA_API} API.
 */
public class PlaceAutocompleteAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<AutocompletePrediction> implements Filterable {

    private static final String TAG = "PlaceAutoComAdapter";
    private static final CharacterStyle STYLE_BOLD = new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD);
    /**
     * Current results returned by this adapter.
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> mResultList;

    /**
     * Handles autocomplete requests.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * The bounds used for Places Geo Data autocomplete API requests.
     */
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;

    /**
     * The autocomplete filter used to restrict queries to a specific set of place types.
     */
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;

    /**
     * Initializes with a resource for text rows and autocomplete query bounds.
     *
     * @see android.widget.ArrayAdapter#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context, int)
     */
    public PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, GoogleApiClient googleApiClient,
                                    LatLngBounds bounds, AutocompleteFilter filter) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1);
        mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the bounds for all subsequent queries.
     */
    public void setBounds(LatLngBounds bounds) {
        mBounds = bounds;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the number of results received in the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    /**
     * Returns an item from the last autocomplete query.
     */
    @Override
    public AutocompletePrediction getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        // Sets the primary and secondary text for a row.
        // Note that getPrimaryText() and getSecondaryText() return a CharSequence that may contain
        // styling based on the given CharacterStyle.

        AutocompletePrediction item = getItem(position);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        //TextView textView2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        textView1.setText(item.getDescription());
        //textView2.setText(item.getDescription());

        return row;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the filter for the current set of autocomplete results.
     */
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                // Skip the autocomplete query if no constraints are given.
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the (constraint) search string.
                    mResultList = getAutocomplete(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        // The API successfully returned results.
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
                // Override this method to display a readable result in the AutocompleteTextView
                // when clicked.
                if (resultValue instanceof AutocompletePrediction) {
                    return ((AutocompletePrediction) resultValue).getDescription();
                } else {
                    return super.convertResultToString(resultValue);
                }
            }
        };
    }

    /**
     * Submits an autocomplete query to the Places Geo Data Autocomplete API.
     * Results are returned as frozen AutocompletePrediction objects, ready to be cached.
     * objects to store the Place ID and description that the API returns.
     * Returns an empty list if no results were found.
     * Returns null if the API client is not available or the query did not complete
     * successfully.
     * This method MUST be called off the main UI thread, as it will block until data is returned
     * from the API, which may include a network request.
     *
     * @param constraint Autocomplete query string
     * @return Results from the autocomplete API or null if the query was not successful.
     * @see Places#GEO_DATA_API#getAutocomplete(CharSequence)
     * @see AutocompletePrediction#freeze()
     */
    private ArrayList<AutocompletePrediction> getAutocomplete(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Starting autocomplete query for: " + constraint);

            // Submit the query to the autocomplete API and retrieve a PendingResult that will
            // contain the results when the query completes.
            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mPlaceFilter);

            // This method should have been called off the main UI thread. Block and wait for at most 60s
            // for a result from the API.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // Confirm that the query completed successfully, otherwise return null
            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error contacting API: " + status.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting autocomplete prediction API call: " + status.toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");

            // Freeze the results immutable representation that can be stored safely.
            return DataBufferUtils.freezeAndClose(autocompletePredictions);
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected for autocomplete query.");
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code, but can you please instruct on how do it? I am quite new to android studio. Sorry sir.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your code

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append("&components=country:ph");
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
```

with this one

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(PLACES_API_BASE + TYPE_AUTOCOMPLETE + OUT_JSON);
        sb.append("?key=" + API_KEY);
        sb.append(""); // THIS SHOULD BE LEFT BLANK
        sb.append("&input=" + URLEncoder.encode(input, "utf8"));
```